# Kinesis Client Library : multiple workers for a stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have a .war in which we have a Kinesis Application which processes a stream which contains a single shard. We deploy two instances of the war in production. As a result, I would end up with two workers working on a single stream with a single shard. What is the recommended way to deal with this issue? I tried deploying two wars on my dev machine locally, and it seems to be fine in the sense that each record is being processed only once. I know that AWS recommends one instance per shard. From their docs:

```
Typically, when you use the KCL, you should ensure that the number of instances does not exceed the number of shards (except for failure standby purposes). Each shard is processed by exactly one KCL worker and has exactly one corresponding record processor, so you never need multiple instances to process one shard.
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably fine most of the time.
The KCL will handle will this for you.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-ddb.html

The case you want to check if a worker dying after processing some records, but before checkpointing. In this case, the worker that takes over will reprocess some records (from last checkpoint).
Can your application handle reprocessing of records?

see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-duplicates.html